# What is the purpose of using load(array) when checking to see if something exists?

Tags: php, arrays, joomla, associative-array

I am attempting to debug a php script I did not write. In order to check if a location already exists, they used the following:

```
$locTable = JTable::getInstance('Location', 'DPCalendarTable');
if ($locTable->load(array('latitude' => $data['latitude'],'longitude' => $data['longitude'])){  
   $_eventLocCache[$data['alias']] = (int)$locTable->id;
}
```

What is the purpose of "..->load(array..."?

Comment: You'd have to look at what that method does in the JTable class to know what it's doing with the array

Comment: Thanks, But what is the purpose of the "load" before the parenthesis?

Comment: It would be good for you to rewrite the question so it's not a debugging question. That or move the question to [joomla.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use Joomla it retrieves data from the table called `Location`

- JTable::load() - Loads a row from the database and binds the fields
  to the object properties.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that load was part of jtable, that clears it up!

Comment: You should accept the answer.

Comment: You are welcome @HamletHub but i see question needs editing :)